# I need a solution on jquery toggle event.

Tags: javascript

Add toggle event on this html, here is the **html code.** i need the toggle event for more row.But its only works for first one, when i add more but it not works for second and third one.

```
<div class="faq_description">
                    <div class="faqs_text">
                        <h3 id="click_question">simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting ?</h3>
                        <p id="toggle_text">the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown
                                printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
                                It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leapthe industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown
                                printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
                                It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="faqs_text">
                        <h3 id="click_question">simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting ?</h3>
                        <p id="toggle_text">the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown
                                printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
                                It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leapthe industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown
                                printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
                                It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

JavaScript Code for This HTML:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#click_question").click(function(){
    $("#toggle_text").toggle(1000);
});
```

});

Comment: Really you posted the code as pictures?

Comment: use class instead of id , paste your code here in question

Comment: There could be an issue, because you use id instead of class

Comment: Agreed with the comments above. Your HTML is not valid because of the duplicate ids. I believe that the jQuery team hasn't tested this scenario and nor they should

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your solution,change `id` to `class`

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".click_question").click(function(){
        $(this).closest(".faqs_text").find('.toggle_text').toggle(1000);
    });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="faq_description">
                        <div class="faqs_text">
                            <h3 class="click_question">simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting ?</h3>
                            <p class="toggle_text">the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown
                                    printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
                                    It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leapthe industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown
                                    printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
                                    It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="faqs_text">
                            <h3 class="click_question">simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting ?</h3>
                            <p class="toggle_text">the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown
                                    printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
                                    It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leapthe industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown
                                    printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
                                    It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Hope this solution will helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use classes rather than an ID to do what you want. Here is an example using your HTML:

```
<div class="faq_description">
  <div class="faqs_text">
    <h3 id="click_question" class="this-question">heading 1</h3>
    <p id="toggle_text" class="this-text">the text 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="faqs_text">
    <h3 id="click_question" class="this-question">heading 2</h3>
    <p id="toggle_text"  class="this-text">the text 2</p>
  </div>
</div>`
```

And here is the jQuery to accomodate the change:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".this-question").click(function() {
     $(this).parent().find("p.this-text").toggle(1000);
  });
  $(".this-text").click(function() {
    $(this).toggle(1000);
  })
});
```

The first main difference is the inclusion and use of classes instead of IDs. IDs are too specific for what you need. The next big change is the use of `$(this).parent().find("p.this-text").toggle(1000);` instead of `$("#toggle_text").toggle(1000);`. The use of parent() gets the 'faqs_text' div which can then be used to find it's child 'p.this-text', and then apply toggle to it.

As a bonus, I've also added a little bit of extra code so that it's possible to click the text content or the header to hide the text.

Here is a working [pen](https://codepen.io/robwelan/pen/rzeKqo).

NOTE: I haven't corrected your IDs. IDs should always be unique. For example, you can have one ID called 'toggle_text_1' and another called 'toggle_text_2'. For the purposes of what you're trying to achieve with this jQuery exercise, the IDs aren't required at all.

Answer (score 0):

Change your id's to classes and make the following changes to your  jquery code

```js
$('.faq_description .toggle_text').hide();

$('.faq_description .click_question').click(function(e){
    
    e.preventDefault();
    // hide all span
    var $this = $(this).parent().find('.toggle_text');
    $(".faq_description .toggle_text").not($this).hide();
    
    
    $this.slideToggle();
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="faq_description">
                    <div class="faqs_text">
                        <h3 class="click_question">simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting ?</h3>
                        <p class="toggle_text">the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown
                                printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
                                It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leapthe industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown
                                printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
                                It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="faqs_text">
                        <h3 class="click_question">simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting ?</h3>
                        <p class="toggle_text">the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown
                                printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
                                It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leapthe industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown
                                printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
                                It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Explanation:

1.var $this = $(this).parent().find('.toggle_text');
 when you click on a question, toggle_text of that question is stored in 'this' variable.
2. $(".faq_description .toggle_text").not($this).hide();
   now 'this' variable is compared with all another toggle_text present in your code and they are made hidden.
 3.$this.slideToggle();
    now 'this' variable is  toggle(here you can use slideToggle() or toggle() but slideToggle() will add some good effect.)

Comment: In my code, all other answers are being hidden when you click on the other question(i.e., only one question with answer will display other answer will be hidden), which is the proper format of creating an faq section

Comment: @arina afrin mitu accept the answer or comment your further requirements.